# My .zshrc throws a VCS_INFO_set:12: bad math expression: illegal character: {

Tags: zsh

```
grep -i vcs ~/.zshrc
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable bzr git hg svn
zstyle ':vcs_info:*:prompt:*' actionformats "${FMT_BRANCH}${FMT_ACTION}" "${FMT_PATH}"
zstyle ':vcs_info:*:prompt:*' formats       "${PR_BRIGHT_BLUE}git:(${PR_RESET}${FMT_BRANCH}${PR_BRIGHT_BLUE})${PR_RESET}" "${FMT_PATH}"
zstyle ':vcs_info:*:prompt:*' nvcsformats   ""                             "%~"
        vcs_info 'prompt'
    local vcs_cwd='${${vcs_info_msg_1_%%.}/$HOME/~}'
    local cwd="${color2}%B%20<..<${vcs_cwd}%<b"
  local git='$vcs_info_msg_0_'
```

I get

```
VCS_INFO_set:12: bad math expression: illegal character: {
```

but it seems to work? Nonetheless the error is worrysome.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: @chx : There is no zsh arithmetic expression in the example you posted.